# img onclick do not work when in quores

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code like this

```
 var cross=  '<img src="./img/cross.png"height="25px" width="25px" style="float: right; 
                              vertical-align: top"' + 'onclick="alert('+1+');">';
```

The img shows correctly but the alert do not work. 
Also, I wonder if there some tips when write code with many quotes or there is some other way to implement.

Comment: ideally you would avoid using inline handlers like you have here, then you don't need to worry about getting the quotes for it right as an added benefit

Comment: Why didn't you use this code? what does those extra quotes do?

`var cross= '<img src="./img/cross.png"height="25px" width="25px" style="float: right; vertical-align: top" onclick="alert(1);">';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
var temp = "+1+";
var cross= "<img src='./img/cross.png' height='25px' width='25px' style='float: right; vertical-align: top' onclick='alert(temp)'">;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, there is so much wrong with this I don't know where to start.

```
<img src="./img/cross.png"height="25px" width="25px" style="float: right; 
                      vertical-align: top"' + 'onclick="alert('+1+');">';
```

1. Attributes should have spaces between them. Not sure if this is part of the strict HTML spec, but sure helps readability. `<img src="..." height="...">`
2. Width and height on an `<img>` tag are integer attributes, not CSS. So `<img width="25" height="25">`
3. Paths starting with dot are unnecessary, since relative paths are assumed to go from the current directory. Just `src="img/cross.png"` is what you want.
4. Why are you concatenating two literal strings? It makes sense sometimes to keep the line length from getting out of hand, but in your case it makes hard-to-follow quotation and escaping even more difficult.
5. The `onclick` part is a single quoted string with double quotes inside, which is fine, but then the string terminates at the first single quote. So you get `onclick="alert(` followed by `+1` which gets cast to a string for `onclick="alert(1` then the final string is appended (close paren, semicolon, double quote, right angle bracket). Amazingly this appears to be syntactically valid JavaScript.

In short, escape the single quotes in your `alert` statement with backslashes.